# New RecyclerView item on click of button

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am a bit new to Android so forgive for any shortcomings.

I have a FloatingActionButton in the `activity_main.xml` and whenever it is clicked I want it to take me to a new activity with two EditText fields and there is another FAB there.
What I want to do is that whenever text is input and the FAB in the `activity_new_goal.xml` is pressed it should create a RecyclerView with the text in the `@+id/edit_goalTitle` text.
It is showing me error of incompatible types in `return data;` and showing cannot resolve method `getData()` in the `MainActivity.java`

Here's my code:

`MainActivity.java`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;
private RVAdapter adapter;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private EditText editGoalTitle;
private String stringGoalTitle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    NavigationDrawerFragment drawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
    drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar));

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.goalList);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    adapter = new RVAdapter(getApplicationContext(), getData());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));



}

public RVData mSetRecyclerGoalTitle(View view) {

    editGoalTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_goalTitle);
    editGoalTitle.setText(R.string.dummyTxt);
    stringGoalTitle = editGoalTitle.getText().toString();


    public List<RVData> getData () {
        List<RVData> data = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] titles = {};
        if (stringGoalTitle != null) {
            titles = new String[]{stringGoalTitle};
        } else {
            titles = new String[]{"DummyText1"};
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <= titles.length; i++) {
            RVData current = new RVData();
            current.goalTitle = titles[i];
            data.add(current);
        }
        return data;
    }
}

public void newGoal(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewGoal.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

`RVData.java`:

```
import android.widget.CheckBox;

public class RVData {
CheckBox checkBox;
String goalTitle;

}
```

`RVAdapter.java`:

```
public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.myViewHolder> {

List<RVData> data = Collections.emptyList();
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public RVAdapter(Context context, List<RVData> data) {
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.goal_row, viewGroup, false);
    myViewHolder holder = new myViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(myViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    RVData current = data.get(position);
    viewHolder.title.setText(current.goalTitle);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}

class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    //@Bind(R.id.goalRowTitle)
    TextView title;
    //@Bind(R.id.goalRowCB)
    CheckBox checkBox;

    public myViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.goalRowTitle);
        checkBox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.goalRowCB);
    }
}
}
```

`activity_main.xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
style="@style/DefaultLayoutStyle"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<include
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    layout="@layout/app_bar" />


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    style="@style/FABStyle"
    android:onClick="newGoal"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
    app:borderWidth="0dp" />

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/app_bar">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/goalList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:name="com.kellarapps.zeal.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

`activity_new_goal.xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
style="@style/DefaultLayoutStyle"
tools:context="com.kellarapps.zeal.NewGoal">

<include
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    layout="@layout/app_bar" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/goalTitle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/app_bar"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingEnd="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"

    android:paddingStart="5dp">

    <TextView
        style="@style/DefaultTVStyle"
        android:text="@string/goal" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_goalTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/goalHint" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/goalDescription"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/goalTitle"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingEnd="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingStart="5dp">

    <TextView
        style="@style/DefaultTVStyle"
        android:text="@string/goalDescription" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/description"
        android:maxLines="3" />

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fab2"
    style="@style/FABStyle"
    android:onClick="mSetRecyclerGoalTitle"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_done"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"/>
```

`NewGoal.java`:

```
public class NewGoal extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_goal);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_new_goal, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    if(id == android.R.id.home)
    {
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

`goal_row.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingStart="10dp">

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/goalRowCB"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/goalRowTitle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/dummyTxt"
    android:textColor="@color/TextColor"
    android:textSize="17sp" />
```

Comment: next time please post your stack trace (error log), so it will be easier to know what's wrong with your code.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see, what you're trying to do is to return some info from the **NewGoal** activity to the **MainActivity**. You cannot access to the layout of other activity to recover the content of its views.

That's usually done using **startActivityForResult**.

Take a look at the developers reference:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
public RVData mSetRecyclerGoalTitle(View view) {

    editGoalTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_goalTitle);
    editGoalTitle.setText(R.string.dummyTxt);
    stringGoalTitle = editGoalTitle.getText().toString();


    public List<RVData> getData () {
        List<RVData> data = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] titles = {};
        if (stringGoalTitle != null) {
            titles = new String[]{stringGoalTitle};
        } else {
            titles = new String[]{"DummyText1"};
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <= titles.length; i++) {
            RVData current = new RVData();
            current.goalTitle = titles[i];
            data.add(current);
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

to

```
public void mSetRecyclerGoalTitle(View view) {

    editGoalTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_goalTitle);
    editGoalTitle.setText(R.string.dummyTxt);
    stringGoalTitle = editGoalTitle.getText().toString();

}

public List<RVData> getData () {
    mSetRecyclerGoalTitle(null);
    List<RVData> data = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] titles = {};
    if (stringGoalTitle != null) {
        titles = new String[]{stringGoalTitle};
    } else {
        titles = new String[]{"DummyText1"};
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= titles.length; i++) {
        RVData current = new RVData();
        current.goalTitle = titles[i];
        data.add(current);
    }
    return data;
}
```

Comment: NullPointerException at `adapter = new RVAdapter(getApplicationContext(), getData());` & `editGoalTitle.setText(R.string.dummyTxt);` & `mSetRecyclerGoalTitle(null);`

Answer (score 0):

There are many things going wrong with your code.

Firstly, this method does not make any sense:

```
public RVData mSetRecyclerGoalTitle(View view) {

editGoalTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_goalTitle);
editGoalTitle.setText(R.string.dummyTxt);
stringGoalTitle = editGoalTitle.getText().toString();


public List<RVData> getData () {
    List<RVData> data = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] titles = {};
    if (stringGoalTitle != null) {
        titles = new String[]{stringGoalTitle};
    } else {
        titles = new String[]{"DummyText1"};
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= titles.length; i++) {
        RVData current = new RVData();
        current.goalTitle = titles[i];
        data.add(current);
    }
        return data;
    }
}
```

It's wrong from the first line. `edit_goalTitle` is not from `activity_main` so you will not find that View.

Next you wrote a method definition inside a method? No that's not gonna happen. That's why the IDE gives you an error.

Then you declared the `onClick` in xml:

```
android:onClick="mSetRecyclerGoalTitle"
```

However, this onClick thing will fail as well, because `MainActivity` inflated other xml file, not `activity_new_goal.xml`. This will only work if you put the `mSetRecyclerGoalTitle` method inside the activity that inflates `activity_new_goal.xml`.

Comment: After trying N1to's solution it is giving me this: NullPointerException at `adapter = new RVAdapter(getApplicationContext(), getData());` & `editGoalTitle.setText(R.string.dummyTxt);` & `mSetRecyclerGoalTitle(null);`

Comment: I told you already, you are getting NPE because `edit_goalTitle` is not in `activity_main.xml` so you cannot get a reference to the EditText.

Comment: So can you tell me how to link it so that I don't get this? I mean like how to direct it to the `activity_new_goal.xml` EditText?

Comment: Just do some google search on how to inflate a layout. In your case you already have `NewGoal` which is an activity that inflates `activity_new_goal.xml`. So you will find your `edit_goalTitle` if you use `findViewById` there.

Answer (score -2):

You have a space between `getData` and the brackets `()` in your definition of the method:

```
public List<RVData> getData () {
    ...
}
```

Change to:

```
public List<RVData> getData() {  // <-- deleted space
    ...
}
```